Monoids that produce sequences without runs
I'm not sure how to phrase this question properly, but is there a name for a property of some monoids/operators that, when applied to a sequence, produce a sequence without runs?
For example, suppose I have the monoid $\text{Add} = (\mathbb{N}, +, 0)$. Then, if I fold a sequence that has no zeros (the monoidal unit), I'll always get a sequence without runs:
$\text{fold}_{\text{Add}}(( 1, 2, 3 \}) = ( 1, 3, 6 ) \\
\text{fold}_{\text{Add}}(( 2, 3, 1 \}) = ( 2, 5, 6 )$
But, for example, the monoid $\text{Max} = ( \mathbb{N}, \max, -\infty )$ does not have this property:
$\text{fold}_{\text{Max}}(( 1, 2, 3 )) = ( 1, 2, 3 ) \\
\text{fold}_{\text{Max}}(( 2, 3, 1 )) = ( 2, 3, 3 )$
Both are pairwise associative and commutative, but, for $x, y \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$, we always have $x + y > x$ but this is not the case for $\max(x, y)$.

An "injective series" (for a slightly extended notion of series: essentially, a fold)?  That said, associativity and the sequentiality of fold defeat each other somewhat...

What is the mathematiclal definition of a "sequence without runs"?
